# создание домашней сети на Node.js

Tags: node.js, сервер

Посмотрел сайт и не нашел нужного решения. Хотя кажется что оно должно быть простое.

Я создал самый простой Node.js сервер на Компьютере и хочу к нему подсоедениться через планшет или телефон.

```
//localhost:3000
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log('server work');
    res.end('1')
}).listen(3000);
```

При запуске браузера компьютера все хорошо. Как и предполагается

> `http://localhost:3000/`

рисует цифру "1". Но не видит с телефона.
Ip адрес своей машины я нашел как "192.168.1.97" ,
С телефона я пробовал разные комбинации вводить в адресной строке :

```
192.168.1.97:localhost:3000
http://192.168.1.97:localhost:3000
192.168.1.97
```

Но результатов это не дало. В дальнейшем планирую усложнить код и выставить его на Хостинг.

Чтоб убедиться в том что ip я нашел правильно, прикладываю ipconfig
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `http://192.168.1.97:3000` и фаервол настройте на входящие соединения.

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо огромное. Очень быстро и по делу !